# Some android devices encounter java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

This is my first question here, hopefully it won't be ignored.

Application was published 3 months ago. Generally app was tested on multiple android devices and works fine, but some customers experience crashes.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lostnfound.mobile_app.Past_mapactivityinstance
at com.lostnfound.mobile_app.Past_map_fragm.onCreateView(Past_map_fragm.java:52)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:845)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1156)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:270)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862)
at com.lostnfound.mobile_app.Past_act.onCreate(Past_act.java:44)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Past_map_fragm code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map")
            .setContent(new Intent(getActivity(), Past_mapactivityinstance.class));
    ...
}
```

I understand that NoClassDefFoundError is really general error. I can't figure out why the application works fine on most of android devices, but some encounter this error.

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov and ajpolt: sorry not full question text was entered by the time you was reading it.

Comment: I've seen this before when an activity was referenced in the manifest using the full package name.  I solved it by removing all but the class name then dotting it.  Something like com.somebody.app.someClass --> .someClass.  Weird but I wasn't the only one who'd seen it..

Comment: It looks like you're using Maps in your application. "The Maps external library is not part of the standard Android library, so it may not be present on some compliant Android-powered devices." Have you tried installing the apk to an emulator that doesn't have the Google Maps API and see if it produces the same error?

Comment: @Simom Thanks but in the Manifest I use relative path name (not full).

Comment: @ajpolt Thanks, it is an idea. I will try and post a feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post a LITTLE more code, perhaps more help could be given. It looks like somewhere you are attempting to use Past_mapactivityinstance, but I don't see it in the 3 lines of code you've posted. I would be willing to bet that if you were to search for Past_mapactivityinstance in your code and replace it with Live_mapactivityinstance, you'd get some different behavior from your app.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when was entering the question. Of course inside "Past_map_fragm" class "onCreateView" method the "Past_mapactivityinstance.class" is used (the question text was edited). This is the line where application encounters a critical error on some Android powered devices. Let me know if you need me to post some extra code.